# Using Python + Selenium, how to find whether the page title contains a particular string?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

To assert the page title, I do not want to do a hard check but rather a soft one, something like a string pattern match on the page title. For this, here is an excerpt of my code which unfortunately is not working:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15)
wait.until(lambda driver:self.driver.title.lower().startswith('Checkout'))
self.assertIn("Checkout", self.driver.title)
```

This is the exact title of the page: **Checkout - HarXYZ**

Can someone please point out where I am making a mistake? Is there any other way of asserting the page title through string pattern match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self.driver.title.lower().startswith('Checkout')` will always return False, because `Checkout` contain uppercase letter `C`.

```
wait.until(lambda driver:self.driver.title.lower().startswith('checkout'))
```

Comment: Thanks **falsetru**. It worked! Such a silly mistake!!! I have just one more doubt. Just like startswith(), do we have something like contains() or some other method for string match comparison?

Comment: @Praveen, There is `in` operator. `needle in haystack`.